# SEO Yoast custom Open Graph description

Tags: wordpress, seo, facebook-opengraph, yoast

I got a site and running the SEO Yoast plugin.
I've noticed that this plugin automatically fill the open-graph meta tags in on the webpages when you thick this option.
Now that's all great, but it uses the page description also in the open-graph description, and I would like to enter another custom description for open-graph without changing the page meta description.
I have not found a way to do this, and I was hoping you guys could help me with this issue.

Cheers all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever page you want to edit those descriptions for, click the social button on the left side of your Yoast SEO widget. You should be able to customize everything from there.

Image included at the link below.

[Where To Add Custom Social Media Titles and Descriptions Using Yoast SEO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQECp.png)

Hope this helps! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Problems like this are the reason I wrote my own plugin for managing Open Graph. Yoast make some strange and often restrictive assumptions about which content should be used for different OG tags. I think mine is the perfect balance of works-out-of-the-box, and yet flexible enough for developers to filter as they need. You should check it out! Very easy to set a custom OG description (and even custom Twitter description beyond that).

https://wordpress.org/plugins/complete-open-graph/